# Create most of one SOAPClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a soap services with a lot of calls.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$result1 = $client->service($valeurs1); 
$result2 = $client->service($valeurs2); 
...
$resultn = $client->service($valeurs3);
```

My problem happens if I exceed a certain number of calls, I fall in time-out.
I can increase the max_execution_time but I'm not a fan of this solution.

If I put everything in one call, it does not pass either (too much data)

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$result = $client->service($valeurs1 + $valeurs2 + .... + $valeursn);
```

Is there a way to stop my service soap in the execution of my php script to recreate a new one every call?

```
$client1 = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$result1 = $client1->service($valeurs1); 
// stop connection soap
$client2 = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$result2 = $client2->service($valeurs2); 
// stop connection soap
...
$clientn = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$resultn = $clientn->service($valeursn);
// stop connection soap
```

My php version is 5.3 
I can not use "keep_alive" which appeared in 5.4

If you have an idea, that would be great! :)

(Sorry for my english : translate.google :))

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the service"? Cancel / stop waiting for the previous call? Or just free / release resources used by the connection? Since SOAP uses HTTP for transport,   I wouldn't expect a connection to be open between calls.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I want every service `$client->Service(..)` end.
Currently, if I call too, I fall into the timeout defined by `max_execution_time`, with one or more `new SoapClient`.
I therefore conclude that I am in a single execution.
To avoid this, I would like to have as many different SOAP implementation that service call ($client->Service(..)). 
I do not know if this is possible ...
I hope I have been clearer.

Comment: `max_execution_time` is about how long your PHP script has been executing, not details like SOAP calls. In fact, the time spent waiting for a response from the SOAP service won't be counted, as PHP is effectively 'asleep' while it waits.

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much!
I did not take the problem as it should! Thank you again. :)

Comment: @IMSoP : If you are interested, I created an edit to explain the context of my question and my resolution. Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make a return to close my question and all the better if it can served to someone.

Already again thank you to @IMSoP have answered me and have referrals.

The principle of my dev is updated many elements (on a real example, it can range from 1 to 12000).
I had gone to make a call to each update, or the time of the call to the webservice more processing time, I passed largely the actual execution time of PHP (max_execution_time).

So I went on a different principle, I send a file to update my elements and the time is much better.
:)
Here is an example SOAP call with a file for those who are interested.
:)

```
$url_base = 'http://www.exampletoto.tata/';

// SOAP Client Options
$options = array();
$options['location'] = $url_base. 'webservice/soap';
$options['uri'] = $url_base ;  
$options['encoding'] = 'ISO-8859-15';
$options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;


$nom_fic = 'file_name.csv';

$handle = fopen('C:\\TMP\\' . $nom_fic, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize('C:\\TMP\\' . $nom_fic));
fclose($handle);

$info = array('nom_fic'    => $nom_fic,
              'taille_fic' => filesize('C:\\TMP\\' . $nom_fic));

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options); 
$result = $client->updateService($info, $contents);
```